# How to take string value of XML including other tags from within an xml object

Tags: php, simplexml

Using PHP and simplexml if possible, I'd like to parse the following example document to extract the whole value of what is contained within the text tag, including the paragraph, content, and whatever else tags are there.

```
<section>
<id root="71EB365C-A4F5-D758-0C51-B8DA375805CD" />
<code code="34066-1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="BOXED WARNING     SECTION" />
<title mediaType="text/x-hl7-title+xml">USE IN PREGNANCY</title>
<text><paragraph><content styleCode="bold">When used in pregnancy during the second and     third trimesters, ACE inhibitors can cause injury and even death to the developing fetus.      </content>When pregnancy is detected, quinapril tablets USP&#160;should be discontinued as soon as possible. See <content styleCode="bold">WARNINGS</content>, <content styleCode="bold">Fetal/Neonatal Morbidity and Mortality</content>.<linkHtml href="#W_fetal" /></paragraph><content styleCode="bold" /><content styleCode="bold" /><content styleCode="bold" /></text>
<effectiveTime value="20070112" />
</section>
```

When I reference it in php/simplexml as such, it returns nothing.

```
$message .= $xml->section->text;
```

This is a simple example for a huge project where the contents of the text tag vary greatly, so I cannot just solve this one example specifically.

I'd like the output to be:

```
<paragraph><content styleCode="bold">When used in pregnancy during the second and         third trimesters, ACE inhibitors can cause injury and even death to the developing fetus.          </content>When pregnancy is detected, quinapril tablets USP&#160;should be discontinued as     soon as possible. See <content styleCode="bold">WARNINGS</content>, <content     styleCode="bold">Fetal/Neonatal Morbidity and Mortality</content>.<linkHtml href="#W_fetal"     /></paragraph><content styleCode="bold" /><content styleCode="bold" /><content     styleCode="bold" />
```

Many thanks, as I'm sure there is a simple solution that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Did you really checked that your code is not working? Your code looks correct. Check in HTML source code as well. As your data has tags which are not not known HTML, so it will not appear on webpage without extra css for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [asXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asXML.php) method. It will give you the xml of the node you ask, like this: (didn't test)

```
$message = $xml->section->text->asXML();
```

Answer (score 1):

The data on the **text** element should have been wrapped with **CDATA**.

It should have been like this:

```
<section>
   <id root="71EB365C-A4F5-D758-0C51-B8DA375805CD" />
   <code code="34066-1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="BOXED WARNING     SECTION" />
   <title mediaType="text/x-hl7-title+xml">USE IN PREGNANCY</title>
   <text><![CDATA[<paragraph><content styleCode="bold">When used in pregnancy during the second and     third trimesters, ACE inhibitors can cause injury and even death to the developing fetus.      </content>When pregnancy is detected, quinapril tablets USP&#160;should be discontinued as soon as possible. See <content styleCode="bold">WARNINGS</content>, <content styleCode="bold">Fetal/Neonatal Morbidity and Mortality</content>.<linkHtml href="#W_fetal" /></paragraph><content styleCode="bold" /><content styleCode="bold" /><content styleCode="bold" />]]></text>
   <effectiveTime value="20070112" />
</section>
```

Comment: I agree. If those elements have no meaning to the document, the whole blob should be in CDATA. Not just out of some kind of theorical purity but mainly because it will make parsing faster and reading easier.